# which is better way to run a file system monitoring service?

Tags: python, linux, filesystemwatcher, inotify

I need to monitor NAS **file system disk space**, whenever file-system disk space goes above from a threshold value, I am I deleting oldest files from file system to bring back file system disk space below to threshold value.
I read several article which suggested me two alternatives:

- by creating a **daemon process** which will run in background
- by creating a **script and run through crontab**

which would be a better way to run a file system monitoring service?

I need to run the monitoring script every 60 sec.For both options I will use python.
it will run on *nix(unix/linux) environment.

Comment: You haven't really given enough detail or requirements to make a decision.  All you've said is that it will be "monitoring", and it needs to do this monitoring every 60 seconds, and no other functions.  Either approach is fine for that.  Will it send email?  Will it update a web page somewhere?  Will it run on windows, linux or mac?  What filesystems will it monitor, just local ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script (you wouldn't need python for this task, just `df` and `find`). This is pretty lightweight, needs less code than a daemon (much less maintenance in the long run), and running scripts once a minute by cron is not unheard of. :-)